# Add time in minutes to a time in 12 hr format

Tags: iphone, xcode4.5

I need to add some dynamice number of minutes to the time in 12 hr format.
I have a time in 12hr format as 1:45 PM .How can I add some dynamic number of minutes like 15,30,60 to it and get as 2:00 PM if 15 minutes is added.When It is 12:00 PM the added time should become 1:00 PM if 60 minutes is added.In android we can split do the corresponding process.But couldn't understand how to do in iphone.

Same case when the time is in AM format

Any suggestions/help would be appreciable.

Comment: whats the issue then? You have minutes devide them / 60 you will get hours to plus if total minutes are less then 60 then dont touch them when they reach 60 do +1 total minute= minutes in time + minutes to be added

Answer (score 0):

suppose now time =1:45 that means

hour=1 & minutes=45 & you have to add 15 min.then

```
    minutes=minutes+15
    if(minutes==60)
    {
    hour=hour+1;
    minutes=0;
    }
   else if(minutes>60)
   {
   hour=hour+1;
   minutes=minutes-60;
   }
   else
   {
    minutes=minutes;
   }
```

you can get hour,minute,seconds by following code

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
unsigned int unitFlags = NSHourCalendarUnit|NSMinuteCalendarUnit|NSSecondCalendarUnit;
NSDateComponents *comp = [calendar components:unitFlags fromDate:date];
NSInteger h = [comp hour];
NSInteger m = [comp minute];
NSInteger s = [comp second];
NSLog(@"%i,%i,%i", h,m,s);
```

UPdated1: for setting AM to PM or PM to AM , simply check whether hour is grater than 12.

that means suppose now it is PM.

if your newly calculated hour is `hour>12` then change it to AM

Comment: But how to separate that 1 and 45 PM .and add to 45 only and get the returned string as 2:00 PM?I mean I need to split the time into two parts.?

Comment: That is OK But I have to get whether it is AM or PM.So can I split the time(1:45 PM ) into two parts.First part is 1 and second part is the part after : i.e 45 PM.and again split 45 PM into two parts45 and PM and add to 45 .?

Comment: I have stored time in a NSString variable

Comment: @Sindhia:why ypu are storing it in string , why not in integer

Comment: Its is coming from the service url.So.Can I convert it to int by parsing or anything else?

Comment: k I did this: int number=[time4 intValue];

Comment: Suppose I have 11:45 PM adding 15 min to it changes to 12:00 AM right.How can I do it .I mean how can I check it for PM and AM ?'

Answer (score 0):

Use `NSDate` to create an date object from your time. Then create [`NSDateComponents`](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/Reference/Reference.html) from that date and add the minutes to the date.
After which you can create a new `NSDate` object wich you can pressent to the user in the 12HR format use `NSDateFormatter`